# Equality between frozensets

Tags: python, set, immutability

Example:

```
>>> tuple((1, 2)) == tuple((2, 1))
False
>>> frozenset((1, 2)) == frozenset((2, 1))
True
```

Frozen sets are immutable. I would expect that equality between immutable objects should by determined by order, but here obviously that is not the case.

How can I discard frozensets with same elements and different order, without casting to different type?

Comment: Because `frozenset` are immutable unordered collection of unique elements.

Comment: I think you simply can't because there's no order in sets (nor frozensets). "frozen" refers to the immutable aspect of the frozensets, not the order.

Comment: The code in the question is a misleading comparison. `frozenset` is an immutable version of a `set`, not having anything to do with a `tuple`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasnt aware that frozensets are unordered.

Comment: Being unordered is a defining feature of the set ADT, like other associative collections (e.g. dictionaries).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you give a reference where set definition state that implementation should not include ordered members? It's just that Python does not have ordered set in standard library.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) states following in the first sentence: "set is an abstract data type that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values".

Comment: it is frozenSET not frozenTUPLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't, since as pointed out in the comments, sets and frozensets are unordered data structures. Here are some excerpts from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)<sup>*</sup> to support this statement:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>
> There are currently two built-in set types, `set` and `frozenset`. The `set` type is mutable — the contents can be changed using methods like `add()` and `remove()`. Since it is mutable, it has no hash value and cannot be used as either a dictionary key or as an element of another set. The `frozenset` type is immutable and hashable — its contents cannot be altered after it is created; it can therefore be used as a dictionary key or as an element of another set.

<sup>*</sup> Python 2.7.12

---

For a better grasp of the equality issue, I would encourage you to run the following snippet using the [Online Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=tu_1+%3D+tuple((1,+2%29%29%0Atu_2+%3D+tuple((2,1%29%29%0Afs_1+%3D+frozenset((1,+2%29%29%0Afs_2+%3D+frozenset((2,1%29%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=4):

```
tup_1 = tuple((1, 2))
tup_2 = tuple((2, 1))
fs_1 = frozenset((1, 2))
fs_2 = frozenset((2, 1))
```

This is an extremely handy tool that renders a graphical representation of the objects in memory while the code is executed step by step. I'm attaching a screenshot:

[image]